# Match character and extract data from bottom rows

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a large tab-delimited file and a part of it is like:

```
25      M   X   A   A   X   S
25_a    M   K   A   A   R   S
25_b    M   A   A   A   V   S
31      M   A   A   A   V   S
31_a    M   A   A   A   V   S
31_b    M   A   A   A   V   S
```

I am trying to play with three rows at a time, the first row contains a reference sequence (actual sequence) whereas the next two rows reflect its variants. I am trying to do two things:

First thing is that from the first row (reference line (25)), I am trying to identify (match) a character (X)  and trying to only keep the corresponding characters in the bottom two rows (25_a, 25_b) to get something like shown below,

```
25      M   X   A   A   X   S
25_a        K           R   
25_b        A           V
```

Secondly, If there is no (X) in the reference (31) line, then remove the corresponding two rows (31_a, 31_b) to get something like this:

```
31      M   A   A   A   V   S
```

And a final output should be like

```
25      M   X   A   A   X   S
25_a        K           R   
25_b        A           V   
31      M   A   A   A   V   S
```

I know we can remove after specific character using sed command but I am struggling to get the desired output. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you please explain better how do you get that output? It is confusing by now. It will probably be a good job for awk, I'd add that tag too.

Comment: Are the `X`s always in those two columns?

Comment: No, it can be in different columns

Comment: @WaqasKhokhar, I'll try to come up with a `sed` only answer this evening.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;N;/^.._./!{/^\S+\s.*X/!{P;d};s/^(\S+\s*)(.*\n\S+\s*)(.*\n\S+\s*)/\1\n\2\n\3\n/;:a;/\n\n/{s/\n+/\n/g;s/.$//;b};s/\n([X\t])(.*\n.*)\n(.)(.*\n.*)\n(.)/\1\n\2\3\n\4\5\n/;ta;s/\n(.)(.*\n.*)\n(.)(.*\n.*)\n(.)/\1\n\2\n\4\n/;ta}' file
```

Append the next two lines to the current line.

If the reference line does not contain `X`, print the first line and delete the remaining two.

Otherwise: insert three newlines, one each following the keys of each of the three lines in the pattern space.

Using a loop, test the character following the first inserted newline to be either an `X` or a tab and if so move the newline over it and do the same with the other two lines.

If the character following the inserted newline is not either of the above, move over it for the reference line and remove it in the other two lines.

Repeat until the whole of the first line is processed.

At the end of the line processing the inserted newlines are removed and the result printed.

Answer (score 0):

Given this input (I've used spaces here to make it prettier, but it should be tabs)

```
25      a   X   X   q   X   c
25_a    b   g   l   r   w   d
25_b    c   h   m   s   y   e
31      d   i   0   0   z   f
41      d   i   X   X   z   f
41_a    e   j   o   u   a   g
41_b    f   k   p   v   b   h
41_c    f   k   p   v   b   h
47      d   i   0   0   z   f
47_a    e   j   o   u   a   g
47_b    f   k   p   v   b   h
```

and this desired output (spaces should be tabs)

```
25      a   X   X   q   X   c
25_a    b           r       d
25_b    c           s       e
31      d   i   0   0   z   f
41      d   i   X   X   z   f
41_a    e   j           a   g
41_b    f   k           b   h
41_c    f   k           b   h
47      d   i   0   0   z   f
```

The following script does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S sed -Ef
/^[0-9]+\t/!d
/^[0-9]+\t.*X/{
  :next
  N
  /.*\n[0-9]+_[^\n]*$/!bprint
  :mark
  s/^([^\n]*)\t([^\t\x0][^\n]*\n)/\1\x0\2/
  s/^(.*)\n(.*)\t([^\t\x0])([^\n]*)$/\1\n\2\x0\3\4/
  tmark
  :clean
  /^([^\x0]*)\x0[^X]/s/^([^\x0]*)\x0(.*)\n([^\x0]*)\x0(.*)$/\1\t\2\n\3\t\4/
  /^([^\x0]*)\x0X/s/^([^\x0]*)\x0X(.*)\n([^\x0]*)\x0.(.*)$/\1\tX\2\n\3\t\4/
  tclean
  bnext
  :print
  h
  s/(.*)\n.*/\1/
  p
  x
  s/.*\n(.*)/\1/
  /X/bnext
}
```

This script is more general than necessary, as it deals with any number of lines or columns. I have also tested with a small chuck of your input containing a fair amount of `X`es (columns from 240th to 260th) and it works.

On the other hand, it is very slow. I could simplify it by considering that the lines are always in groups of 3; that would certainly reduce the complexity of the script.

But it was fun to do it more general.